# Cognito User Pools CUSTOM_AUTH flow doesn't provide NewDeviceMetadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We're using the CUSTOM_AUTH flow in Cognito User Pools to implement our own MFA, which is skipped for remembered devices. We've been able to authenticate existing devices while using this flow but hit a road block. It seems NewDeviceMetadata is null when authenticating with a CUSTOM_AUTH flow, even when no DEVICE_KEY is supplied during initiate auth /SRP_A.

Any idea with how we can proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I hit a case where amplify-js throws `NewDeviceMetadata of undefined` error when doing a CUSTOM_AUTH flow. Turns out amplify expects the custom auth challenge name, returned from the lambda trigger, to be exactly `CUSTOM_CHALLENGE`.